# NullPointerException when trying to setText

Tags: android, textview, android-arrayadapter, getview

The textView shoud be instanced, I don't know why it says NullPointerException at textView.setText("test");

```
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_navdrawer, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.getTag(android.R.id.text1);
    textView.setText("test");

    if (position == mSelectedItem) {
        textView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color. holo_blue_dark));
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    } else {
        textView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }

    return textView;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger.  It's null because the textview does not exist in the current layout or it's ID is not android.R.id.text1.  Either way, the debugger will show you instantly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: "android.R.id.text1" should be just "R.id.text1", no ?

Comment: are you using fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Use [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) to get views.